# jquery popup effect 'onclick' submit button (WITHDRAWN)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onsubmit

Since I am a beginner, I have a beginner's question.

Using the famous [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) plugin. It is called in the head like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Normally the script is attached by adding the class-name:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">...</a>
```

My present difficulty arises because I would like to run the fancyBox pop-up after the user submits a form:

```
<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get">
    ...(google API stuff etc, etc)...
    <input type="submit" value="...">
```

My research to this point has led me to conclude that I probably have to use `onsubmit` or `onclick` within the

```
<input type="submit">
```

However, my experimentation has proven a futile effort.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

========================================

**UPDATE: (1/7/2013)**

I am withdrawing my question because I have apparently wandered into subject matter that is slightly above my head at the moment. I choose not to delete the question in case someone in the future may find something of some use here. Thank you for your help everyone.

My reason: it appears that Google directions does not permit display in `<iframe>`. That being considered, configuring a workaround for `fancyBox` would be far too complex. I am abandoning the fancyBox and have gone with plain old Javascript:

[as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207482/center-window-open-on-form-submit)

Comment: please dont use pre when you already formatting by 4 space or ctrl+k

Comment: stackoverflow yelled at me and commanded me to use cmdK. thanks for the constructive criticism though.

Comment: You would like to run the fancyBox pop-up after the user submits the form? But the page will change after the form is submitted...

Comment: ajax submission of form? and may be then manually calling the fancybox after the completion of ajax rquest...

Comment: The action of your form is linking to **googlemaps** page. so after the submission the page will be changed. you should have control on the new page,if you have so we can popup the fancy box

Comment: @derek - sorry for the delay in responding - busy day at work, no time for forums.  I am using _fancyBox_ in my design to display popup `iframe` and `img`. In the interest of maintaining this theme, I was hoping to display the google directions as such. I intend to have the user enter their zip code into an `input`, and be presented with the _fancyBox_ upon submission.

Answer (score 1):

Post the form using $.ajax gives you the greatest control. You can then control the success and error conditions from the client side.

To do this you will either need to catch the submit event:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
 ajaxUpdate();
 return false;   
});
```

Then create a function:

```
function ajaxUpdate(){
 var formSerial = $('#form').serialize();
 $.ajax({
        url: '<url to post to>',
        dataType: "text",
        type: "POST",
        data: formSerial,
        success: function(text) {
          $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        },
        error: function(text) {
          alert('error in posting');
        }
});
}
```

You can then do what you like in the success and error blocks.

To load a window you could add the following to your function:

```js
if(confirm("Do you want to open the directions?")){
      $.fancybox({
                'titleShow': false,
                'width': 370,
                'height': 300,
                'href': <URL>,
                'type': 'iframe'
              });
}
```

Comment: In this case the url will go to the google maps page. how can he send back any data from a page where he doesn't have control on.

Comment: @jeremy - thank you for your time. My programming skills don't progress too far beyond an intermediate level understanding of html and css. Help walk me through this. But first, let me clarify my objective. I am using [fancyBox](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/) in my design to display popup `iframe` and `img`. In the interest of maintaining this theme, I was hoping to display the google directions as such. Using basic google maps api, I intend to have the user enter their zip code into an `input`, and be presented with a fancyBox popup `iframe` upon submission.

Comment: if(confirm("Do you want to open the directions?")){
                $.fancybox({
                    'titleShow': false,
                    'width': 370,
                    'height': 300,
                    'href': "",
                    'type': 'iframe'
                  });
 }

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery submit buttoin it can be possible :

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
  return false;
});
```

After fancy box 'ok'  button  click submit the form ..

Hope this idea will helpfull.

Comment: hi @the suresh thank you for the reply. jQuery being a foreign language to me, I must ask how exactly do I write my `<form>` markup? I tried: `<input type="submit" target="fancybox" />` to no avail.